# Enabling WIFI hotspot from a computer without usb debugging

Tags: adb, fastboot, broken-screen

Is it possible to enable WIFI hotspot from a computer without usb debugging being enabled?

I got a phone with broken LCD and i'm unable to enable usb debugging.

Comment: Broken screen means "nothing visible" and/or "touch does not work"? Which device are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

No. ADB doesn't work without debugging.

However you can try your vendor native app, like LG PC Suite or Samsung Kies. It probably can have phone management capability and enabling/disabling its features.